# Bundler works in Powershell but not as post build event

Tags: javascript, servicestack

I've written a small powershell script that compiles all my typescript files and then bundles them. It works just fine when I run the script from within the powershell editor, but when I try to run it as a post-build event, the build just hangs.

As soon as I remove the bundler line from the script, the build works (ie: it compiles the ts files)

What would cause this behavior?

```
$TypeScripts = get-childitem "$(get-location)\RockyMountainArts.Web\scripts\src\*\*.ts" -recurse

foreach ($tsFile in $TypeScripts){
    tsc $tsFile
}

&"$(get-location)\RockyMountainArts.Web\bundler\node.exe" "$(get-location)\RockyMountainArts.Web\bundler\bundler.js" "$(get-location)\RockyMountainArts.Web\CSS" "$(get-location)\RockyMountainArts.Web\Scripts"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need to figure out a different way of getting the solution directory in PowerShell.

My ps script uses `$(get-location)` to get the current directory.

This works fine when running from the script editor since my script is located in the root of the solution, HOWEVER, This does NOT work fine in a post-build since the "new" current directory is located in the `bin` folder.

My current work-around is to use absolute paths.